# Xcode Server testing error

Tags: ios, xcode, server

Can someone help me with this error? 
It doesn't happen all the time.

Bot Issue: error. Uncategorized.

Issue: Test target XXXTests encountered an error (Unable to run app in Simulator If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach .

Integration Number: 25.

Integration URL: [URL]

Description: Test target XXXTests encountered an error (Unable to run app in Simulator If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-219ca4f378bf6fe93706b10d491ecf0e/Session-2014-11-12_12:16:32-PU5ZJk.log).

Comment: Why don't you do what the error says? ;)

Comment: @HAS I'm new to Xcode server. Could you explain? I mean, where to attach that log file? Aparently this error appears when trying to test on Resizable iPhone

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I cannot provide you a solution, but I would file a radar at bugreport.apple.com. There you can attach the log file as explained in the error. This doesn't solve this but it may be fixed in a future release.

Comment: I see this _intermittently_ on our Xcode Server as well, always with the "resizable" simulators.  I've just unchecked them on our bots for now.